Error: Docker container with react, vite and tailwindcss, getting error Unexpected token 'export'
I am busy setting up a project where I want to use Docker with react, vite and tailwinds.
With docker I get the following error trying to install tailwind
error message: docker
/app/postcss.config.cjs:1
export default {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`
or: previous error
error message: docker
 docker vite Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'tailwindcss' imported from /app/vite.config.js
Currently the setting are working when I run the project without docker. it works fine
github:
https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx
I have been looking for solution online for a couple of days unfortunatly with no succes.
Trying out several configuration settings from different blogs. Unfortunatley with little success.
I expect my project to work with a docker container, and use tailwinds with no problems

export default is module syntax. There is a .cjs extension on the file which indicates common.js.

Thank you for you comment. I just tried to re-install a new react-vite project and reinstall everything, without changing file names (so no .cjs extension).
I am still getting the issue.

@J.Titus by the way I have updated my posted github repository and removed the extension cjs from the postcss.config file

The code in your current repository builds and runs fine for me.
docker-compose build && docker-compose up

However, I could not access the site via port 5173. To get this to work I made a change to package.json, specifying 0.0.0.0 as the host for the dev script:
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },



Thank you much for helping me out with this! I have it working as well now! :D
I was not aware of the significance of configuring packag.json to make it work,
I am going to some more research in to that
